# SQL query with the lower execution plan cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this tables and this query and I need equal query with the lower execution plan cost.

```
CREATE TABLE PilotSkills
(pilot CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 plane CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (pilot, plane));

CREATE TABLE Hangar  -- ALWAYS CONTAINS AT LEAST ONE TUPLE
(plane CHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY);

SELECT DISTINCT pilot
  FROM PilotSkills AS PS1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM Hangar
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                  FROM PilotSkills AS PS2
                 WHERE (PS1.pilot = PS2.pilot)
                   AND (PS2.plane = Hangar.plane)));
```

Comment: `uery with the lower cost`  are you talking about execution plan cost ,also tag the dbms you are using

Comment: paste the current plan here :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: also be aware,execution plan always sums upto 100%,you might want to add few more parameters like improving speed,lowering number reads as parameters,when you want to fine tune query

Comment: So, you are attempting to generate... a list of pilots who can fly every plane in the hangar?

Comment: Yes I need this list

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

rextester: http://rextester.com/ORG70581

```
create table PilotSkills (
   pilot char(15) not null
 , plane char(15) not null
 , primary key (pilot, plane)
 );
insert into PilotSkills (pilot,plane) values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3)

create table Hangar(plane char(15) primary key);
 insert into Hangar values (1),(2),(3)    

select ps.Pilot
from PilotSkills ps 
  inner join Hangar h on ps.Plane=h.Plane
group by ps.Pilot
having count(distinct ps.Plane)=(select count(distinct i.Plane) from Hangar i)
```

Depending on your actual tables and data, `distinct` may not be needed in those `count`s.